# ERROR: expected package `PkgAuthentication [4722fa14]` to be registered

Tags: julia, julia-pkg

I am using JuliaPro v1.4 on Windows 10. I was trying to install a package but the REPL got stuck so I interrupted it. Since then I'm no longer able to install any package due to this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the right directory (where the manifest/project file are), just doing `up` and `resolve` in the package manager will resolve this.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't seem to find the correct directory. I tried cd "AppData\Local\JuliaPro-1.4.0-1\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.4.0-1\environments\v1.4" (where these files exist) but the same shows up.

Comment: I have this same issue. @logankilpatrick could you explain your solution in a little more detail?

Comment: Hey Timothy, what part is it clear? It should (hopefully) be As simple as getting into the correct dir and then doing an Up & Resolve. Have you tried those steps?

Answer (score 0):

In the REPL (in the repo where you'd like to install the package):

- Switch to "[Pkg mode](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/REPL/#Pkg-mode)" by typing `]`
- Type `up` + enter
- Type `resolve` + enter
- Try re-installing the desired package